# How to pick string formatter value by using regex

Tags: java, regex

There is a string with formatter:

`Today is %s with degree %d℉.`

How can I pick %s value and %d value by using regex in java?

For Example:

```
Input: Today is Sunday with degree 70℉
Output: Sunday, 70
```

Comment: `Today is (.*) with degree (.*)℉`!?

Comment: Just remember `%s` can be any string including special characters, line breaks etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [java example](https://regex101.com/r/BFBg6I/1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "Today is (\\w+) with degree (\\d+)℉";
final String string = "Today is Sunday with degree 70℉";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Seem that it just work on ascii words. Like `Today is दोस्त with degree 70℉"` , it did not work well. How to solve it?